# Oracle SQL group by queries, Kind of PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

Till now i haven't got a need to post a query, almost everything is available. This is my first question.

I have a different requirement, I have the below table name say alarmdb

------------------INT_ID-----------------------------------------------------   ALARM_NUMBER----------------------------

```
             101212121                               7762
             101212121                               8212
             101212121                               3423
             101313131                               7734
             101313131                               7743
```

Basically its kind of grouping, and pivoting. Final output can be like this.

------------------INT_ID-----------------------------------------------------   ALARM_NUMBER----------------------------

```
             101212121                           7762,8212,3423
             101313131                               7734,7743
```

Kind of shrinking many cells data into one.

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: what version of oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Oracle you have different options.

You can use `LISTAGG` for Oracle 11g+:

```
select int_id,
  listagg(alarm_number, ', ') within group (order by int_id) as alarm_number
from yourtable
group by int_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e15c6/2)

Or you can use `wm_concat()`  for earlier versions:

```
select int_id,
  wm_concat(alarm_number) as alarm_number
from yourtable
group by int_id
```

Comment: WM_CONCAT() is not a documented function, and so shouldn't be relied on in production code.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use, wm_concat is not supported i guess,  am posting the versions below.

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
"CORE 10.2.0.5.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

Comment: @ChandraSekhar I would suggest reviewing the following page which shows some examples on how you can do this in Oracle 10g -- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php